# Traduction pour « Workload » au sens cloud computing ?

Tags: informatique, terminologie

Y a-t-il un terme approprié pour traduire « workload » au sens employé en informatique dans le domaine du cloud computing ?

Comment: La charge de travail ? tu veux parler du workload pour les applications en cloud computing ?
On parle aussi de capacité de calculs, le workload est alors la mesure de cette capacité à l'instant donné.

Comment: On peut aussi simplifier _la charge de travail_ en _la charge_ (tout court). Parfois on parle aussi de _charge CPU_. Mais l'expression est maladroite car elle mélange Français et Anglais. Dans ce cas on pourrait dire la _charge de calcul_ même si c'est un peu connoté mathématiques/calculateur/simulateur.

Answer (score 2):

Comme dit dans les commentaires, "workload" se traduit par "charge de travail".

Suivant le contexte, on peut faire varier l'expression. Les exemples de [superbob](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/10547/superbob) sont bien : "charge", "charge CPU" ou "charge processeur", "charge de calcul".